# List Dialog Fragment - Resources not found exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to see which item is selected by using the "which" variable, but i get this excepiton.
This is my fragment dialog..

```
public class ItemSettingsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.title_settings).setItems(R.array.item_settings_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

And here is the array..

```
<string-array name="item_settings_settings">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
</string-array>

DialogFragment newFragment = new ItemSettingsDialogFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "items_settings");
```

I get this error..

```
05-30 16:00:23.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2060): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

If anybody knows what's wrong.. I can't understand what's wrong.. Please help..

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: Where is that string-array? Is it in the res/values/array.xml file?

Comment: it's in the res/values/strings.xml

Comment: Create a new file called arrays.xml in the values folder. Then use the code above and it should work for you.

Comment: still the same... :\ I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call dialog.dismiss(); before Showing Toast

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer but I've already figured it out in a different way. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out. After adding the code clean your project to make sure everything is ok.

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_settings_settings);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.title_settings).setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've delete the toast message and used Log to write the message and it worked, no more exceptions. I guess someone knows why is that..